# How do I add exception handling messages to Universal Windows apps?

Tags: c#, exception, win-universal-app

I am trying to add exception handling with a corresponding message box to a Universal Windows app. I wanted to just use TryParse or Try-Catch, but I can't figure out what the equivalent to a message box is in universal windows apps. I'm  not particularly worried about the aesthetics of it now, as long as whatever I do conforms to UWP standards so I don't get into bad habits moving forward.

Here is my C#:

```
    double INCHES = 1;
    double FEET = 12;
    double YARDS = 36;

    double userDist, convertDist, distFrom, distTo;
    string unitOfMeasure;

    private void convertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        unitOfMeasure = null;
        distFrom = 1;
        distTo = 1;
        if (inputTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            userDist = double.Parse(inputTextBox.Text);
            if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 || listBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                switch (listBox1.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        distFrom = INCHES;
                        unitOfMeasure = " in";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        distFrom = FEET;
                        unitOfMeasure = " ft";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        distFrom = YARDS;
                        unitOfMeasure = " yd";
                        break;
                }
                switch (listBox2.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        distTo = INCHES;
                        unitOfMeasure = " in";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        distTo = FEET;
                        unitOfMeasure = " ft";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        distTo = YARDS;
                        unitOfMeasure = " yd";
                        break;
                }
                convertDist = (userDist * distFrom) / distTo;
                outputTextBlock.Text = convertDist.ToString("n2") + unitOfMeasure;
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Please select 'From' and 'To' units.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Please input a  number to convert.");
        }           
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inputTextBox.Text = "";
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        listBox2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        outputTextBlock.Text = "";
        distFrom = 1;
        distTo = 1;
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you commented out should work if you also add -

await dialog.ShowAsync();

Answer (score 0):

Like Brian said

```
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Please select 'From' and 'To' units.");
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

should work. I'd also add that you need to mark convertButton_Click as an async method:

```
   private async void convertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Now, I forgot that I did this previously during this project, but when I started on anew one I got a rude awakening: I had added:        using Windows.UI.Popups; to the MainPage C# and the App C#. Where specifically should I be adding that in the future?

Comment: You'll have to add it wherever you plan to use the MessageDialog class.